# For $F = \mathbb{Z}_{11}$ find a basis for the subspace of $F^4$ consisting of solutions of $6x + 2y + 3z + 5w = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

What is really confusing me about this problem is that the field is $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$; if $F = \mathbb{R}$ the basis could be $\{\left(-\frac{1}{3},1,0,0\right), \left(-\frac{1}{2},0,1,0\right), \left(-\frac{5}{6},0,0,1\right)\}$. However, all three of these vectors contain values not in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$, so I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: The vector $(-1/3,1,0,0)$ spans exactly the same subspace as $(-1,3,0,0)$ in $\Bbb R^4$, but the latter exists in $\Bbb F^4$ ($-1/3$ exists in $\Bbb F$ as well, it just isn't trivial to see that it is the same as $7$).

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can get your solutions as elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}^4$.  For instance $-\frac{1}{3}$ may be interpreted as $-1\cdot 3^{-1}=-1\cdot 4=-4=7$ (in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$).

So your first solution vector is $(7,1,0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @paw88789's answer, another way to think about this is by choosing different solutions to the equation in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$. For example, one solution is $(-1,3,0,0)$. The other two basis elements can be thought about in the same way.